# Can I use variable in Numbers cell formula?

Tags: numbers

I have to write a complex formula like this:

```
IF(5−SUM(C35:I35)>0,5−SUM(C35:I35),"")
```

Can I define a variable for 5−SUM(C35:I35)?

Comment: I usually create a (hidden) column to calculate complex formula if I need to reuse the result several times.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best solution would be to just assign your variable formula to a different cell and refer to that one in your main formula.

**Example:**

Cell A1:

```
=5−SUM(C35:I35)
```

Cell B1:

```
IF(A1>0,A1,"")
```

You could then hide the column where the variable is, so you don't have to see it.